# Oracle: Selecting * and aggregate column

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to select fields using the method below?

```
SELECT *, count(FIELD) FROM TABLE GROUP BY TABLE
```

I get the following error

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 9
```

Is it a syntax error or do you have to explicitly define each column rather than using *?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns that are selected in the field should be

- an expression used as one of the group by criteria , or
- an aggregate function , or
- a literal value

For this, you need to indicate the fields you needed and should fit in the following criteria mentioned above.

```
SELECT FIELD1,FIELD2, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY FIELD1, FIELD2
```

If you insist to use the logic of your query, the use of subquery should be helpful.
For example,

`SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN (SELECT FIELD1, COUNT(FIELD1) AS [CountOfFIELD1] FROM TABLE1 T2 GROUP BY FIELD1)T3 ON T1.FIELD1=T3.FIELD1`

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `*` and other columns. If you use an alias, then you can:

```
SELECT t.*
,      count(FIELD) 
FROM   TABLE t
```

Also, your `GROUP BY TABLE` is wrong. You can't group by the table name, you must specify some columns, like this:

```
SELECT   t.customer
,        count(FIELD) 
FROM     TABLE t
GROUP BY t.customer
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `*` you need to give the column names:

```
SELECT a, b, COUNT(FIELD)
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY a, b;
```